# MatPlotLib scatter redrawing extending x Axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to `python` and `matlotlib`. I am trying to draw a scatterplot with `matplotlib` that is grouped by industry. However when I iterate over the industries and add them to the figure the output redraws and extends the axis to the right inside of reusing and rescaling the existing axis. The result makes all the tick marks unreadable and put each industry side by side and not on the same axis:

```
temp = data[data.Year == 2017]
data = pd.read_csv(path, encoding='latin1')
data['Company'] = pd.Categorical(data['Company'])
data['Industry'] = pd.Categorical(data['Industry'])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

for ind in temp.Industy.unique():
   temp2 = temp[temp.Company == ind]

   revGrowth = temp2["RevGrowth"]
   EBITMargin = temp2['EBITMargin']
   scatter_plot = ax.scatter(revGrowth, EBITMargin, s=40, alpha=0.8,label=ind)

plt.legend(loc='upper right', bbox_to_anchor=(1.3, 1.05), fontsize=8, frameon=False)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.xlabel("Revenue Growth YoY (%)")
plt.ylabel("Return on Assets (%)")
plt.title("Industry Growth vs Profitability 2017\n")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig("xx")
```

[image: image 1]

How can I solve this?

Comment: The solution is not to plot strings. Convert your data to numbers first; in this case e.g. `temp2["RevGrowth"].astype(float)`.